# How to get the records from last 60th day to previous days

Tags: mysql

i want to fetch all the records having greater than 60days older. im having create_date column, please suggest a query that satisfies above requirement

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE create_date BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)  AND create_date >'60days'
```

got my query

the right query is

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE create_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY);
```

Comment: you need to atleast try somethihng..

Comment: yea i have tried but failed to retreive

Comment: if you have shown what have you tried, then you would likely have got some help

Comment: If `create_date` is `DATE`, then your edit with `create_date >'60days'` makes no sense - you cannot compare dates with intervals

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, expression

```
x BETWEEN a AND b
```

literally means

```
a <= x AND x <= b
```

If `a > b`, this will yield empty result no matter what.

In other words, order does matter - simply make sure that when using `x BETWEEN a AND b` then `a` must be <= `b`.

For you it means swap dates (and fix some other errors as well):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE create_date BETWEEN '2011-10-14'
          AND NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY
```

**UPDATE**: One more note about using functions `DATE_SUB()` or `DATE_ADD()`.

In general, if you need to compare dates in big table, you should avoid using these functions at all costs! Modern MySQL supports date arithmetic using standard `+` and `-` operators, so expression

```
DATE_SUB(create_date, INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

is equivalent to

```
create_date - INTERVAL 60 DAY
```

Not only this is easier to read, but it also allows server to take advantage of possible index you created for `create_date` column. This speed-up cannot be applied to any function call like `DATE_SUB()` - MySQL does not support functional indexes.

Comment: updated answer - avoid `DATE_SUB()` if you can!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
select * from tablename where datediff(now(), date) > 60
```

I am assuming that `date` stored in a column called `date`, You use your column name instead of `date`.

Hope it works.

Comment: this query will work very slow if table is large. indexing will not help

Comment: no records are fetching by using above query

Comment: see my updates answer as well.

Comment: got my query

    SELECT * FROM mytable where created_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY);

Comment: the query i mentioned will also give you the same result..